# Read from network problem .NET

Tags: .net, network-programming, smtp

I try to develop an simple smtp server, the problem is when I try to read message from network all messages are a string with a lot of "/0" instead of typed command. I use telnet to connect to my application and to type messages.

this is my code:

```
public void StartListen()
        {
            SMTPParser parser = new SMTPParser();
            SMTPResponder responder = new SMTPResponder();
            Listening = true;

            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 25);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(endPoint);
            listener.Start();


            while(Listening)
            {               
                byte[] data = new byte[2048];               
                Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();                
                socket.Receive(data);

                string cmd = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

                if(cmd !="") parser.Parse(cmd, responder);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Socket.Receive` returns the number of read bytes. Currently, you're always getting a string from the 2048 bytes of the buffer, even if only a few bytes are read. Change to:

```
int length = socket.Receive(data);
string cmd = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, length);
```